# how to find attributes of image by javascript

Tags: javascript

I've an Image with attributes like name, width.

and now I'm trying to get an attribute value which is not existing with Image.

```
var title = imgTemp.attributes("Title").value;
```

And it is giving error, because argument `Title` is not there. How can I check this before assign?

Comment: @Sam jQuery just to get an attribute ? really ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getAttribute`:

```
var title = imgTemp.getAttribute('title');
```

If there is no title attribute, it will return `null`.

You can also access the attribute directly as a property:

```
var title = imgTemp.title;
```

It will then return an empty string if there is no title attribute present, which means that you will have the same return value if the title attribute is present but empty, f.ex: `<img title="">`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`element.hasAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.hasAttribute), like so

```
if (imgTemp.hasAttribute('title')) {
  // get it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `attributes` http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/attributes.

```
var title = domElement.title
```